# Pad a Tensor in Torch

Tags: image, image-processing, lua, transform, torch

I have a 100x100 pixel image in a Torch Tensor and I want to implement a "zoom out" transformation. How can I achieve this using the Torch [Image](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/simpletransform.md//) toolbox (or other)?

I have already implemented "zoom in" by simply using image.crop followed by image.resize.

In Matlab, I would calculate the mean grayscale of the image, pad the array n pixels with that colour (keeping the original image centred), and then resize to 100x100 pixels. In there a "pad Tensor" function for Torch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a "pad Tensor" function for Torch?

One possibility is to use the [nn.Padding](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/f58632d24de1b27a113f738c1b5a9dfc00a82921/doc/simple.md#nn.Padding) module from [torch/nn](https://github.com/torch/nn#neural-network-package), e.g.:

```
require 'image'
require 'nn'

local x = image.lena()

local pad  = 64
local pix  = 0
local ndim = x:dim()

local s = nn.Sequential()
  :add(nn.Padding(ndim-1,  pad, ndim, pix))
  :add(nn.Padding(ndim-1, -pad, ndim, pix))
  :add(nn.Padding(ndim,    pad, ndim, pix))
  :add(nn.Padding(ndim,   -pad, ndim, pix))

local y = s:forward(x)

image.display(y) -- this requires qlua
```

**UPDATE**

As can be seen in the [implementation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/efb781d/Padding.lua#L20-L29) padding is obtained by:

1. allocating an output tensor of the expected size post-padding filled with the padding color,
2. filling the area corresponding of the input tensor with the original values thanks to [`narrow`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/ad73aec/doc/tensor.md#self-narrowdim-index-size).

Toy example:

```
require 'torch'

local input  = torch.zeros(2, 5)
local dim    = 2 -- target dimension for padding
local pad    = 3 -- amount of padding
local pix    = 1 -- pixel value (color)

-- (1) compute the expected size post-padding, allocate a large enough tensor
--     and fill with expected color
local size   = input:size()
size[dim]    = size[dim] + pad
local output = input.new():resize(size):fill(pix)

-- (2) fill the original area with original values
local area   = output:narrow(dim, 1, input:size(dim)):copy(input)
```

This gives as output:

```
0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2x8]
```

For specific zero-padding there are other convenient possibilities like:

- [`nn.SpatialZeroPadding`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/efb781d/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialZeroPadding),
- `padzero` and `padmirror` from [koraykv/fex](https://github.com/koraykv/fex/blob/9ba3300/utils.lua#L96-L132).

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try it. Otherwise, I suspect I can make a new tensor of the padded size, copy over the data, and the, resize it.